# Where can I find ERC20 token faucets for testing?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, testnets, faucets

I want to use the Ethereum test network to test token transfers and such, but I can't find any token faucet or anything like it so I can't try out things. Google didn't show anything, only Ethereum faucets.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I will be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Weenus  ERC20 FaucetAnnouncing the Weenus  ERC20 token faucets on the Ethereum mainnet, and Ropsten, Kovan, Rinkeby and Görli testnets](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/WeenusTokenFaucet):

- Search in your Ethereum blockchain explorer for **WEENUS** (18 decimals), **XEENUS** (18 decimals), **YEENUS** (8 decimals) or **ZEENUS** (0 decimals).
- Send a 0 value transaction from your account to the token contract addresses below on your preferred network, and these token contracts will mint 1,000 ERC20 test tokens for your account.

---

### Smart Contract Addresses

- [Mainnet](https://etherscan.io/)

  - WEENUS, 18 decimals - [0x2823589A](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2823589Ae095D99bD64dEeA80B4690313e2fB519#code)
  - XEENUS, 18 decimals - [0xeEf5E2d8](https://etherscan.io/address/0xeEf5E2d8255E973d587217f9509B416b41CA5870#code)
  - YEENUS, 8 decimals - [0x187E63F9](https://etherscan.io/address/0x187E63F9eBA692A0ac98d3edE6fEb870AF0079e1#code)
  - ZEENUS, 0 decimals - [0x0693c3a7](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0693c3a780A0a757E803a4BD76bCf43d438f8806#code)
- [Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/)

  - WEENUS, 18 decimals - [0x101848D5](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x101848D5C5bBca18E6b4431eEdF6B95E9ADF82FA#code)
  - XEENUS, 18 decimals - [0x7E0480Ca](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x7E0480Ca9fD50EB7A3855Cf53c347A1b4d6A2FF5#code)
  - YEENUS, 8 decimals - [0xF6fF95D5](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xF6fF95D53E08c9660dC7820fD5A775484f77183A#code)
  - ZEENUS, 0 decimals - [0xC84f8B66](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xC84f8B669Ccb91C86AB2b38060362b9956f2De52#code)
- [Kovan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/)

  - WEENUS, 18 decimals - [0xaFF4481D](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xaFF4481D10270F50f203E0763e2597776068CBc5#code)
  - XEENUS, 18 decimals - [0x022E292b](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x022E292b44B5a146F2e8ee36Ff44D3dd863C915c#code)
  - YEENUS, 8 decimals - [0xc6fDe3FD](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xc6fDe3FD2Cc2b173aEC24cc3f267cb3Cd78a26B7#code)
  - ZEENUS, 0 decimals - [0x1f9061B9](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x1f9061B953bBa0E36BF50F21876132DcF276fC6e#code)
- [Rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/)

  - WEENUS, 18 decimals - [0xaFF4481D](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xaFF4481D10270F50f203E0763e2597776068CBc5#code)
  - XEENUS, 18 decimals - [0x022E292b](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x022E292b44B5a146F2e8ee36Ff44D3dd863C915c#code)
  - YEENUS, 8 decimals - [0xc6fDe3FD](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc6fDe3FD2Cc2b173aEC24cc3f267cb3Cd78a26B7#code)
  - ZEENUS, 0 decimals - [0x1f9061B9](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x1f9061B953bBa0E36BF50F21876132DcF276fC6e#code)
- [Görli](https://goerli.etherscan.io/)

  - WEENUS, 18 decimals - [0xaFF4481D](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xaFF4481D10270F50f203E0763e2597776068CBc5#code)
  - XEENUS, 18 decimals - [0x022E292b](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x022E292b44B5a146F2e8ee36Ff44D3dd863C915c#code)
  - YEENUS, 8 decimals - [0xc6fDe3FD](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xc6fDe3FD2Cc2b173aEC24cc3f267cb3Cd78a26B7#code)
  - ZEENUS, 0 decimals - [0x1f9061B9](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x1f9061B953bBa0E36BF50F21876132DcF276fC6e#code)

Comment: Very nice service, Bokky! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Bokky! You're the best!

Comment: Bad that metamask doesn't allow transactions with value 0.

Comment: Are you sure this is still working ? i'm sending diverse type of transaction without getting any returned coin, please check this: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xd17009e44fa6108a1c7bb3bbfb63c9e50fefa52f

Answer (score 3):

Here's one - https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x583cbbb8a8443b38abcc0c956bece47340ea1367#readContract .

Send test ETH to the contract and you will get BOKKY tokens in return, 1 for 1.

[E] And you can view your token transfers using https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x583cbBb8a8443B38aBcC0c956beCe47340ea1367 . The EtherScan block explorer does not show the tokens being transferred but it does show the token balance.

Comment: I've tried sending test ether to the contract address but the transactions keep failing.  am I sending to the wrong address?

Comment: I did sent test ETH to the smart contract but got nothing in return. Here more detailed (& noob friendly) instructions: metamask network: "rospten"! Browse the smart contract > click "write contract" > "connect with metamask" > method "3. transfer": insert your test ETH address and the amount (must be at least 1, I thought I could send 0.1 ETH: wrong, use a big number ;) ) > click "write" > in metamask see the conversion rate (100000000000000000000 = 100 BOKKY) & confirm > to see your BOKKY tokens: in metamask "menu" click "add tokens" > "custom token" and paste the smart contract address

Answer (score 1):

### Get test Ether first:

[MetaMask Ether Faucet](https://faucet.metamask.io/)

- Request: 1 Ether

> balance: 174148.33 ether

---

[Ethereum Ropsten Faucet](http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/)

- Request: 3 Ether

> balance: 35615 ETH

---

### After:

- deploy your own token contract and test it; using **remix** and **metamask** for example

or

- go to [MyEtherWallet contracts](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts); change network to **Ropsten**;
  **Select Existing Contract** to interact with

---

*updated: 06-Feb-18*

Comment: I don't understand, I need tokens not ethereum, I can already handle ethereum transfers. but thanks

Comment: @dasjkdj if you have ether, why don’t you just buy tokens directly from any token contract in testnet? Using remix and metamask for example.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks. Is there some sort of web / interface to do it or does it have to be done programmatically?

Comment: You can go to [MyEtherWallet contracts](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) change network to Ropsten and Select Existing Contract to interact with.

Comment: Added information from comments.

Answer (score 1):

Why not deploy an own erc-20 token? You can look for an existing Coin on etherscan.io (f.e. https://etherscan.io/address/0x26B1FBE292502da2C8fCdcCF9426304d0900b703#code), just modify symbol, name, decimals and total supply. So you can create your own ERC-20 token and do with it whatever you want. If you don't want to waste Ether, you can use one of the test-net like KOVAN or ROBSTEN. I prefer the Parity-wallet where you can directly deploy own smart contracts.

Answer (score 1):

here are the links for the rinkeby test net, faucet and instructions on how to use it.
https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/10a98e8078cfd69f7ca892ddbdcf26bc
https://faucet.rinkeby.io/
https://www.rinkeby.io/#stats

Answer (score 0):

As you know, all Erc20 tokens have same rules.
So you can create your own ERC20 token.
I have published an article to explain it in step by step tutorial. Here you are:
https://athamidn.medium.com/step-by-step-get-erc20-test-token-faucet-on-ropsten-d20850375f2c

Answer (score 0):

I released a new ERC20 Token Faucet hosted on: https://www.erc20tokenfaucet.com/

This is the Github repository: https://github.com/Kerry1207/ERC20TokenFaucet

It's a simple web application with two functionalities:

- See My Balance: It's a feature that querying the Kerry Token smart contract and allow you to see over the ERC20 token information also your Kerry Token balance;
- Minting Kerry Token: It's a feature that permit you to minting a 1 unit (this is a constant) of Kerry Token without restrictions.

This is a screenshot of website:
[image]

### INFORMATION KERRY TOKEN:

*Token Address:* 0xcf185f2F3Fe19D82bFdcee59E3330FD7ba5f27ce

*Token Name:* KerryToken

*Token Symbol:* KTK

*Token decimals:* 18

*Network where it's available:*:

- Goerli
- Sepolia (Upcoming)

### FAUCETS ETHER ON GOERLI TESTNET:

- https://goerlifaucet.com/
- https://goerli-faucet.slock.it/

### FAUCETS ETHER ON SEPOLIA TESTNET:

- https://faucet.sepolia.dev/
- https://faucet-sepolia.rockx.com//